# uploading geoDataFrame as .shp in GEE : multipolygon grid crossing the antimeridian

Tags: geospatial, geopandas, google-earth-engine, h3

I have created a multipolygon grid covering the entire globe using h3 library. from the code below

```
from shapely import Polygon, multipolygons
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame as gdf

from h3 import h3
import folium

# Polyfill a Geo Json with hexagons
geoJson1 = {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[[90,-180],[90,0],[-90,0],[-90,-180]]]}
geoJson2 = {'type': 'Polygon', 'coordinates': [[[90,0],[90,180],[-90,180],[-90,0]]]}
hexagons = list(h3.polyfill(geoJson1, 1)) + list(h3.polyfill(geoJson2, 1))

# Plot hexagons
polylines = []
for hex in hexagons:
    polygons = h3.h3_set_to_multi_polygon([hex], geo_json=False)
    outlines = [loop for polygon in polygons for loop in polygon]
    polyline = [outline + [outline[0]] for outline in outlines][0]
    polylines.append(polyline)
    
hex_list = [Polygon(h) for h in polylines]
    
grid_gdf = gdf(geometry=hex_list, crs="EPSG:4326")
# Concatenating all the separate dataframes into one big DataFrame
grid_gdf.to_file("h3_test.shp")
```

I am trying to upload "h3_test.shp" as a .shp asset in GEE, but I get this error :

> 

Error: Projection exception. Ensure the projection is specified correctly and the coordinates are within its valid area. Detailed error: Unable to transform edge (33.965356, -166.528928 to 33.965380, -166.528957) from EPSG:4326 PLANAR to EPSG:4326.. (Error code: 3)

Some of the polygons are defined accross the antimeridian. e.g :

```
[(9.615942399155195, 179.77693144202632), (5.889921754313889, 179.21716082489448), (2.9040374505798128, -178.02519665249852), (3.8210244943304374, -174.31673738369324), (7.9727938308414075, -173.38014762578527), (11.05195584369349, -176.35806599111405), (10.46324037683843, -178.23815999124182), (9.615942399155195, 179.77693144202632)]
```

And I wonder if this could be the reason for the error...

I have no more clue, but any help or hint would be very appreciated.
Thank you very much in advance !

Comment: I don't know all the libraries involved, but I'm guessing this is a lat/lng vs lng/lat order issue. Your coords can't be projected because the longitude coords are interpreted as latitude and out of range. If this is correct, using `geo_json=True` will probably fix.

Comment: @nrabinowitz Thank you for the answer ! I'm also thinking this lat/long problem could be the issue. But could you be more precise about this `geo_json = True` argument ? There is no such argument in geopandas.GeoDataFrame . Where should I use it ?

Comment: In `h3_set_to_multi_polygon`, where you currently have `geo_json=False`. This will cause the coords to be output in lng/lat order, rather than lat/lng. I'm guessing that since you're using shapely, it will expect x/y input -- longitude corresponds to `x` and latitude corresponds to `y`.